# Intelli-sense not showing the method onResume() in android

Tags: android

When I am writing `onResume()` method in MainActivity.java 
the Intelli-sense doesn't show the method 
Instead it shows syntax error on token `"onResume"`,delete this token and 
if I write from @override next lines manually 
the error doesn't come 
Please tell the reason for the error!

Comment: Sounds like a IDE issue. Afaik intelli-sense is VisualStudio? Maybe tag your question with the IDE you're using (and mention it in the question)?

Comment: Post exactly the code you use that shows the error, and the code that doesn't.